# Show given metric is equivalent

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(X,d)$ be a metric space. Prove that the function 
 $$\rho(x,y) = \frac{d(x,y)}{ 1 + d(x,y)}$$
 defines an equivalent metric on $X$.  (**Metrics $d_1$ and $d_2$ are called equivalent,  if every convergent sequence in the metric $d_1$ converges also to the same point in the metric $d_2$ and vice-versa**).

**Attempt**: Assume there is a convergent sequence $x_n$ that converges to $x$ in metric $d(x,y)$. Thus, given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $0 \leq d(x_n,x)< \epsilon$. Then, 
\begin{align*}
1 \leq 1+ d(x_n,x) < 1+ \epsilon \\
\implies \frac{1}{1+ d(x_n,x)} \leq 1 \\
\implies 0 \leq \frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+ d(x_n,x)} < \frac{\epsilon}{1+ d(x_n,x)} < \epsilon \\
\implies \rho(x_n,x) < \epsilon\\
\end{align*}

Thus $x_n$ that converges to $x$ in metric $\rho(x,y)$.

Now, assume $x_n$ that converges to $x$ in metric $\rho(x,y)$. Thus, given $\epsilon>0$ $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $0 \leq \rho(x_n,x)< \epsilon$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+ d(x_n,x)}  < \epsilon \\
d(x_n,x) < \epsilon + \epsilon d(x_n,x)\\
 d(x_n,x) < \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} \\
\end{align*}

**Is the procedure correct? Also I am stuck at the end. I cannot show $d(x_n,x) < \epsilon$**

Please note: There are solutions in this website that show equivalence but use a different definition for the equivalent metric.

**Edit: (Based on Arthur's suggestion)**

assume $x_n$ that converges to $x$ in metric $\rho(x,y)$. Thus, there $\exists N$ such that $\forall n > N$ we have $0 \leq \rho(x_n,x)< \frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$.
\begin{align*}
\frac{d(x_n,x)}{1+ d(x_n,x)} (1+ \epsilon) < \epsilon \\
d(x_n,x) (1+\epsilon)< \epsilon + \epsilon d(x_n,x)\\
d(x_n,x) < \epsilon \\
\end{align*}

Thus $x_n$ converges to $x$ in metric $d(x,y)$.

Comment: Well, since $\lim_{\epsilon \to 0+} \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon}=0$...

Comment: For the second part, begin with finding an $N$ such that for all $n>N$ we have $0\leq \rho(x_n, x)<\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ instead (which you can do, since $\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon}$ is a positive number and $x_n$ is convergent), and see where that takes you (using the same procedure).

Comment: $f(z)=\frac{z}{1+z}$ is a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}^+$, hence the only non-trivial point is to prove that $\rho(x,y)$ is actually a metric. But that follows from the fact that $f(z)$ is increasing and concave.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $$ \rho = \frac {d}{1+d}$$

Note that for $$0\le \rho \le 2/3$$ we have $$ \rho \le d \le 3\rho $$

Thus  $$ d\to 0 \iff \rho \to 0$$

The convergence in one metric is equivalent to the convergence to the other metric.

Thus the metrics are equivalent.

Comment: I have to use a different definition for equivalent metric.

Comment: You may use my solution as a hint to prove your $\epsilon $ method of convergence.

Comment: The stuff that I wrote, is that correct?

Comment: Of course your proof is right. All you have to add is $ d(x_n,x) < \frac{\epsilon}{1-\epsilon} < 3 \epsilon
 $ for $0< \epsilon <2/3$